# Error when compile the primer example code using g++ on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c++, g++

The code is from **C++ primer(3 third)**.
The error is :

*filterString.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
filterString.cpp:32:68: error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >’ to ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string*}’ in initialization*

pls help me analyse the error,
thanks.

code:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class InputIterator>
void filter_string(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, string filt_elems =  string("\",?.")) {
    for (; first != last; first++){
        string:: size_type pos = 0;
        while ((pos = (*first).find_first_of(filt_elems, pos)) != string::npos)
            (*first).erase(pos, 1);
    }
}

bool length_less (string s1, string s2) {
return s1.size() < s2.size();
}

int main() {
    istream_iterator<string> input(cin), eos;
    vector<string> text;

    copy(input, eos, back_inserter(text));

    string filt_elems("\",.?;:");
    filter_string(text.begin(), text.end(), filt_elems);
    int cnt = text.size();

    string *max = max_element(text.begin(), text.end(), length_less);
    int len = max->size();

    cout << "The number of words read is " << cnt << endl;
    cout << "The longest word has a length of " << len << endl;
    cout << "The longest word is " << *max << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are working from a book or some other old (in internet time) source you may be dealing with a change in the understanding of how things works as the language has gotten better specified in time. Setting a `-std=` might let you use a earlier understanding in the compiler.

Comment: Sorry ,I can't understand totally . Especially the words :"Setting a -std= might let you use a earlier understanding in the compiler" . Could you explain it from point to point! Thanks very much!

Comment: G++ takes arguments of the form `std=c++98` or `std=c++=0x`. Picking the right one *might* get g++ to handle the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is interesting.  Iterators behave much like pointers, but not exactly.  In particular, you can't convert an iterator to a pointer.

However, you can change this code to use an iterator as a sort of string* pointer:

```
vector<string>::iterator max = max_element(text.begin(), text.end(), length_less);
```

That declares max to be not a pointer to a string, but an iterator into a vector of strings, which is what the max_element algorithm returns when applies to a vector of strings.

You can also use a pointer, but it's a bad habit.  Just for testing the idea, you can:

```
string *max = &*max_element(text.begin(), text.end(), length_less);
```

The *max_element(...) returns a reference to the string the returned iterator points to (just like dereferencing a real pointer) and & creates a (string*) pointer to that string.

This invites trouble, since a structural modification of the vector could quietly invalidate that pointer.  Subsequent use of the pointer would be treating "random" memory as a string object.  Even worse, it might work during your testing and not fail until the software was shipped!

A decent implementation of iterators should detect the invalidation and throw an exception.  A predictable fail is better than a random meltdown.

Comment: I would rephrase it to "A decent implementation of iterators should detect the invalid assignment at compile time and generate an error." That is what gcc is doing. Visual C++ is generating a similar error.

Comment: Side remark, with a modern compiler one could just write "auto max = max_element(text.begin(), text.end(), length_less);".

Comment: About compile-time detection of invalid assignments: I don't think that's really feasible.  That would require the compiler to keep track of iterators, and the language does not really provide for that.  There's nothing wrong with structural modification of a collection while a previously-used iterator is still in scope.  It's the use of that iterator afterward that's an error...and then only if the collection decides that the specific modification actually should invalidate the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

In line 32 ,

```
std::max_element(text.begin(), text.end(), length_less);
```

this function returns a forward iterator addressing the position of the first occurrence of the largest element in the range searched and not a string .

What you can do instead of this line:

```
string *max = max_element(text.begin(), text.end(), length_less);
```

you have to do this ,

```
//First find the index of the max_element , by subtracting the forward iterator you get from calling max_element from the iterator for first element .

       int index=max_element(text.begin(), text.end(), length_less) - text.begin();

//And then find string stored on that index.

       string *max = text.at(index);
```

Comment: It is not about the std namespace , it is what you get from the function . you get a forward iterator and you are casting it as a string .

Comment: I got it. thanks very much. vector<string>::iterator max = max_element(text.begin(), text.end(), length_less);

Comment: But I think Mike Housky's answer is more clear!So I accept his answer .Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I went overboard. Here is what I think is a more modern solution using lambdas and auto. I leave it to others to decide if it is easier to understand.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class InputIterator>
void filter_string(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, 
                   const string filt_elems = const string("\",?.")) 
{
    for_each(first, last, 
        [filt_elems](string& s)
        {
            s.erase(
                // Shift valid characters up before erasing the undesirable
                remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), 
                    [filt_elems](string::value_type c)
                    { return filt_elems.find_first_of(c) != string::npos; }), 
                s.end());
        });
}

int main()
{
    istream_iterator<string> input(cin);
    istream_iterator<string> eos;

    vector<const string> words;
    copy(input, eos, back_inserter(words));

    const string filt_elems("\",.?;:");
    filter_string(words.begin(), words.end(), filt_elems);
    const int count = words.size();

    // Get a reference to the longest word
    const auto& max_word = *max_element(words.cbegin(), words.cend(), 
        [](const string& lhs, const string& rhs)
        { return lhs.size() < rhs.size(); });
    const int length = max_word.size();

    cout << "The number of words read is " << count << endl;
    cout << "The longest word has a length of " << length << endl;
    cout << "The longest word is " << max_word << endl;

    return 0;
}
```